# Generate codes based on Nominal Variables present in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that has 1000 observations and it has this structure below.

```
Town <- c("TownA", "TownB", "TownC","TownD","Town A", "Town Z")
Ward <- c("Ward B","Ward Z","Ward A","Ward W","Ward X", "Ward ")
DF <- data.frame(Town, Ward)
```

I have another dataset that contains codes that represent the nominal observations of Town and Ward. The codes are the ones to be used for analysis. For example, Town A has the code 23, Town B has the code 15, Town Z has the code 7. Instead of manually creating a new column and populating the codes based on towns,  is there a simpler way to do this in R?

My goal is to mutate a new column that will match the codes with the towns. The dataset has around 200 Towns.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new code table and then do joining:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Town <- c("TownA", "TownB", "TownC","TownD","Town A", "Town Z")
Ward <- c("Ward B","Ward Z","Ward A","Ward W","Ward X", "Ward ")
DF <- data.frame(Town, Ward)

codes <- tribble(
  ~Town, ~Code,
  "TownA", 23,
  "TownB", 15,
  "Town Z", 7
)
codes
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   Town    Code
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 TownA     23
#> 2 TownB     15
#> 3 Town Z     7

DF %>%
  left_join(codes)
#> Joining, by = "Town"
#>     Town   Ward Code
#> 1  TownA Ward B   23
#> 2  TownB Ward Z   15
#> 3  TownC Ward A   NA
#> 4  TownD Ward W   NA
#> 5 Town A Ward X   NA
#> 6 Town Z  Ward     7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>